# Do wide angle lens adapters maintain DOF but still keep the higher FOV?

Tags: wide-angle, wide-aperture

Instead of buying a really high aperture 25mm lens for the bokeh, I was thinking that if I got a .45x wide angle adapter on a 50mm 1.4, I might get the similar results, if not, then a narrower DOF since I would be closer to the subject. However, I'm not sure if a wide angle adapter will keep the depth of field and just increase the field of view. If it does keep the DOF, then what is the cost of it? In other words, does it create too much color aberrations or make the images very soft?

Some details on the specific items I'm looking at:
50mm 1.4 Nikkor
APS-S Nikon D3300
Snap-it digital .45x wide angle adapter

Comment: Shrinking the image on the sensor increases the DOF because the circles of confusion are shrunk, so cover fewer pixels.  It's no different from a normal lens.

Comment: Wouldn't that just decreases the size of the bokeh, but still maintain the same DOF?

Comment: No, it decreases the size of the bokah affects *and* the blur due to focus. The same amount of blur is smaller in the image. Since the image covers more fov, it will be a smaller fearure in the print. If you make the print larger to keep the subject the same size, then dof (and bokah) will be unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you want to employ what's sometimes referred to as the "brenizer method".

It's as complicated as taking many pictures with a longer focal length, wider aperture lens and stitch them together in post processing.

This will give you a wide angle of view (via pano) and a shallow depth of field (via aperture of long lens)

[He explains it on his website in more detail.](http://ryanbrenizer.com/2011/05/brenizer-method-instructions/) If you are concerned about the stitching not working out, well he is apparently doing this handheld on weddings. If one can pull this of in such situations, I guess it's a matter of training and experience

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I overlooked that method (didn't know it was called brenizer though). But that's exactly what I was looking for! I just now need to only try to keep my subject as still as possible for their frame.

Comment: @Muhatashim I guess like in any pano shot, it's advisable to capture the main subject with one image. Stitching somebodies face back together sounds ...painful. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the wide angle adapter is designed, most will reduce the maximum aperture of the lens, so you probably wont gain anything with this approach.

It's worth noting that there will likely be a substantial loss in image quality when shooting through an adapter at f/1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The [Metabones Speed Booster](http://www.metabones.com/products/?c=speed-booster) will give you > 90% of the *original* aperture,  while shrinking the image on the focal plane.  That increases the apeture size (lower f number) when using it to mount a full-frame lens on a APS-C body. Some models support APS-C lenses, which would have the normal issues of any wide adaptor namely how well does the lens pick up image beyond its rated field of view?  You didn't include details of which equipment you were using, but you might inquire on that product's web page to see if it does what you want, or get a rental to try.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the Metabones speed booster is a rear mounted wide converter and so **only** works with full frame SLR lenses on APS-C *mirrorless* cameras. It will **not** work on DSLRs, as there is no space for the adapter (due to the mirror box).

Comment: [It does take APS-C lenses](http://www.metabones.com/products/details/MB-EF-E-BM4) but I don't know what that would mean.

Comment: Yes APS-C lenses will technically fit, and you can also mount the adapter on a full frame mirrorless body, but the image circle will not be large enough in both cases so it's not particularly useful...